# how to concatenate files in linux without line returns

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I want to concatenate 2 files *file1* and *file2* into *file3* without line returns:

```
cat file1 #return AAAAAAA
cat file2 #return BBBBBBB
```

`cat file1 file2 > file3`

```
cat file3 #will return
AAAAA
BBBBB
```

I want to have AAAAABBBBB

Comment: `echo "$(<file1)$(<file2)"`

Comment: Are both the files just one-liners? If not, do you want to remove just the final newline in the first file, or all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
printf "%s%s\n" "$(<file1)" "$(<file2)" >file3
```

Or:

```
echo "$(<file1)$(<file2)" >file3
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe it to `tr` command that will delete new lines:

```
cat file1 file2 | tr -d "\n" > file3
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$ echo $(cat aaa)$(cat bbb)
aaabbb
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pechomp file1 file2 file3... > file.out
```

See [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp).

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `perl -pe chomp ...`, note a space between `-pe` and `chomp`?

Comment: @user3439894: The space is optional.